# xslt 2.0 run-time vs. compile-time possibilities

Tags: xml, xslt

I am reading this page on what XSLT cannot do

http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/nono.html#d1874e1080

and a lot of questions are about dynamically naming something or dynamically choosing an import or template depending on some parameter.

The answer is always: not possible in XSLT.

Now, what exactly are the reasons that some things are not possible at runtime in XSLT? How can I know that something needs to be decided before compilation?

Some things that are not possible include:

> - calling a template whose name is decided at run-time
> - apply-templates using a mode decided at run-time
> - deciding the sort key at run-time
> - conditional include at runtime

In one answer it is said:

> The basic processing model of XSLT (like many other languages!) is
>   that it builds and compiles the stylesheet before it starts reading
>   the input data.

So that's a distinction between compile-time and run-time.

And it says that `xsl:include` is a compile-time issue

Why exactly can't such functionality be achieved at runtime in XSL? I guess it has to do with the fact that the stylesheet can't be changed after compilation, like an .exe can't, but I'm not a computer scientist, so...

How do I know whether something is restricted to compile-time or whether it can be done at run-time (with focus on XSLT)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Some things that are not possible include:
>
> - calling a template whose name is decided at run-time
> - apply-templates using a mode decided at run-time
> - deciding the sort key at run-time
> - conditional include at runtime

These may be *literally* impossible, but **not** *impossible at all* -- even in XSLT 1.0. For example:

- The same effect as deciding the name of the called template or the mode of the applied template at run-time is achieved by a powerful technique that is used as the base for the **[FXSL library](http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.html)**. The FXSL library implements functional programming in XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0. In XPath 3.0 (and XSLT 3.0) the `function` data-type was introduced. **[Functions in 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel-30/#function-items)** are first-class objects of the XDM type system and can be defined, passed as parameters to other functions or returned by functions. So, one would use functions, instead of calling or applying templates.
- There are good techniques for dynamically specifying the sort-keys, for example [**here**](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N6461.html#d9252e953)
- Conditional compilation (including that of `xsl:import` or `xsl:include`) is possible starting with XSLT 2.0 using the `xsl:use-when` attribute -- read below more about this

> Now, what exactly are the reasons that some things are not possible at
>   runtime in XSLT? How can I know that something needs to be decided
>   before compilation?

1. Read a **[good book on XSLT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004QWZTSG)**.
2. Watch a [**training course**](http://app.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1).
3. Read the W3C **[XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt)**, **[2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/)**, **[3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/)** / **[XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)**, **[2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/)**, **[3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/)** / **[XML](http://www.w3.org/XML/)** - related specifications

> How do I know whether something is restricted to compile-time or
>   whether it can be done at run-time (with focus on XSLT)?

**There are a few simple rules**:

1. Any XSLT *directive* is fully processed (compiled) at compile time. A directive is any XSLT element that is a child of the `<xsl:stylesheet>` (or of its synonym `<xsl:transform>`) element.
2. Almost all attibutes of **[XSLT instructions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-xslt-instruction)**/**[elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-xslt-element)** accept AVTs (**[Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)**) -- with the notable exception of the `select` attribute.
3. The `name` attribute of  doesn't accept an AVT or a variable reference.
4. The `mode` attribute of  doesn't accept an AVT or a variable reference.

---

**Statically known values**

In general, statically-known values (such that are known and do not change during compilation) can be used to control how the XSLT processor compiles a stylesheet.

There are a few functions in XSLT 2.0 that can be used to produce static values, such as:

- [**system-property()**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#system-property)
- **[element-available()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-element-available)**
- **[function-available()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-function-available)**

These can be used in static expressions specified as the value of the **[use-when](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conditional-inclusion)** attribute.

The **[use-when](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conditional-inclusion)** attribute can be specified on any XSLT element -- including XSLT directives and XSLT instructions, and is similar to preprocessing instructions in other programming languages, such as `#ifdef` in C. It can even be specified on any literal-result element, and in this case must be prefixed by any prefix bound to the XSLT namespace (typically "xsl:" is used).

In XSLT 3.0 **[static variables](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#static-params)** and [**static expressions**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#static-expression) were introduced. This provides a lot more possibilities for controlling the compile-time behavior of the XSLT processor.

Another, closely-related feature of XSLT 3.0 are the so called [**shadow attributes**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#shadow-attributes).

To get a grasp of these powerful concepts, one needs to read a [**good book**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004QWZTSG) (for now only books on XSLT 2.0 and XSLT 1.0 are available), or watch a [**training course -- on XSLT 2.0**](http://app.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1) and [**on  XSLT 3.0**](http://app.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-3-0-whats-new-part1) .

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! A lot to dig through :)

Answer (score 2):

Read the specification, for http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#include it shows

```
<!-- Category: declaration -->
<xsl:include
  href = uri-reference />
```

so the allowed value for the `href` attribute is a URI reference, not an XPath expression, nor an attribute value template.

The same for `xsl:call-template`, http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#callable-components shows

```
<!-- Category: instruction -->
<xsl:call-template
  name = qname>
  <!-- Content: xsl:with-param* -->
</xsl:call-template>
```

so the `name` attribute value is a qualified name, not an XPath expression, nor an attribute value template.

On the other hand if you look at `xsl:with-param`, http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-with-param, you find

```
<xsl:with-param
  name = qname
  select? = expression
  as? = sequence-type
  tunnel? = "yes" | "no">
  <!-- Content: sequence-constructor -->
</xsl:with-param>
```

where the `select` attribute allows an XPath expression.

So to find out whether some attribute allows you to use an XPath expression to compute values at run-time look at the definition of the element respectively attribute in the XSLT 2.0 specification.

Comment: So your answer means that only XPath expressions and AVTs can be computed at runtime and all the other things (URI, qname) cannot be determined after compilation? 
And under callable components it says that "It is a static error if a stylesheet contains an xsl:call-template instruction whose name attribute does not match the name attribute of any xsl:template in the stylesheet." So the "static error" indicates, that this must be defined before it is compiled and cannot be computed at runtime, right?

Comment: Well, the specification uses the terms static and dynamic error while your question is about compile-time and run-time error, I think we can roughly say that a static error is raised at compile time while a dynamic error happens during the execution of the stylesheet. As for saying "all other things" "cannot be determined after compilation", I would rather say that `href = uri-reference` or `name = qname` attributes are known at compile time while attribute value templates or select expressions are evaluated at run-time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You're actually asking two separate questions:

> Now, what exactly are the reasons that some things are not possible at
>   runtime in XSLT?

Questions about WHY the language is the way it is can be interpreted as asking for historically-correct answers about when and why particular decisions were made, or they can be interpreted as requests for a (post-hoc) technical justification of the status quo. If interpreted as requests for the history, they're usually very difficult to answer, because except in quite rare cases (e.g. the choice of syntax of XPath if-then-else) the decision can't be pinned down to a deliberate choice between two clear alternatives made at a single meeting. More commonly there's a consensus on design principles within the working group and these inform the decisions that are made. One of those design principles is that XSLT is not a macro language: the result of an expression is a value, not an expanded expression.

The request for dynamic evaluation of template names in xsl:call-template and of mode names in xsl:apply-templates has come up repeatedly over the years, and while it would not be at all difficult to define such a feature, the WG has never felt that this was the right way to go. Essentially these are dynamic despatch mechanisms, and the WG felt this wasn't the right way to do dynamic despatch. Allowing a dynamic name in xsl:call-template, for example, would restrict the ability of the optimizer to eliminate templates that aren't used, or to "inline" them within the code of their caller. The primary way of doing dynamic despatch in XSLT has always been the use of apply-templates and match patterns, and XSLT 3.0 introduces a second way, the use of higher-order functions.

> How can I know that something needs to be decided before compilation?

Answer: by reading the spec, or a good reference book. If the spec doesn't say something is computed dynamically, then it isn't.

Comment: My question was more a technical one: I thought this also had to do with  fact that certain information cannot be accessed at runtime anymore or only determined at runtime.
Like in Java e.g. where the compiler cannot determine which overwritten method to call. This must be determined at runtime. I don't understand compilers enough to know what a compiler can resolve and what it possibly cannot know how to resolve.
Or is it really only a design choice?

Comment: Well yes, for example anything that depends on source document input isn't known till run-time, e.g. you can't in general know which template will be invoked by xsl:apply-templates until you see the input data. Unfortunately this isn't really a topic that lends itself to SO question-and-answer format - perhaps a discussion on the mulberrytech xsl-list would work better?